# TempDB started constant disk IO

Tags: sql-server

At around 10am yesterday I started seeing constant read/write activity to the TempDB database via our RedGate SQL monitor.

This is unusual because usually our disk operations are <100kb/s however as you can see from the graph it has started around 10am and continued even after a restart of the host OS.

Does anyone have any pointers for where I can look to identify what queries or transactions etc might be causing this anomolous disk IO?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using Adam Machanic's [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) to view current sessions and see what sessions have high TempDB usage

Comment: Tried this, it doesnt list any active queries.

Comment: Try setting the variables show_system_spids = 1 and show_sleeping_spids = 2 to get info on inactive but still connected sessions and system sessions

Comment: Thanks @HandyD that did the trick! There was one query taking a lot of tempdb allocations which I killed!